# Finding and splitting at a character from a string inside a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, bioinformatics

I have been at this for several days now and tried all sorts of different methods and checked at least 50 different stackoverflow/python library/python news group questions and none have provided much help. (Though I won't be suprised if it is out there and I've missed it).

ANYWAY!

I have a list of lists with strings inside. As follows:

```
[['CAA46951&Homeobox domain&192:248&F&#CDC1C5&NULL&PFAM&Y&433&'],
 ['CAA46951&Homeodomain-like&165:252&S&#CD5B45&NULL&SCOP&Y&433&'],
 ['5330400P12&WD domain, G-beta repeat&131:168&F&#FF8C69&NULL&PFAM&Y&296&'],
 ['5330400P12&WD domain, G-beta repeat&173:210&F&#FF8C69&NULL&PFAM&Y&296&'],
 ['5330400P12&WD40-repeat&1:296&S&#00FF7F&NULL&SCOP&Y&296&'],
 ['AAH62206&Cell division protein&38:311&S&#00CED1&NULL&PFAM&Y&425&'],
 ['AAH62206&P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolases&36:279&S&#00FFFF&NULL&SCOP&Y&425&']]
```

I want to split each string into a seperate string, in the one list (so [['a','b','c'],['a2','b2','c2']] sort of list instead of [['a&b&c'],['a2&b2&c2]]

I have tried everything from enumeration with for loops, to recursive functions and I can't get it to work. I know this is a REALLY nooby question but PLEASE help.

(it may be note worthy that the list gets passed in as a txt. file and converted to a list of lists of strings. Originally it would be:

`CAA46951&Homeobox domain&192:248&F&#CDC1C5&NULL&PFAM&Y&433&`
`CAA46951&Homeodomain-like&165:252&S&#CD5B45&NULL&SCOP&Y&433&`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LofL=[['CAA46951&Homeobox domain&192:248&F&#CDC1C5&NULL&PFAM&Y&433&'], 
      ['CAA46951&Homeodomain-like&165:252&S&#CD5B45&NULL&SCOP&Y&433&'], 
      ['5330400P12&WD domain, G-beta repeat&131:168&F&#FF8C69&NULL&PFAM&Y&296&'], 
      ['5330400P12&WD domain, G-beta repeat&173:210&F&#FF8C69&NULL&PFAM&Y&296&'], 
      ['5330400P12&WD40-repeat&1:296&S&#00FF7F&NULL&SCOP&Y&296&'], 
      ['AAH62206&Cell division protein&38:311&S&#00CED1&NULL&PFAM&Y&425&'], 
      ['AAH62206&P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolases&36:279&S&#00FFFF&NULL&SCOP&Y&425&']]

newL=[]      
for L in LofL:
    newSubL=[]
    for e in L:
        for s in e.split('&'):
            if s:
                newSubL.append(s)
    newL.append(newSubL)
```

Output:

```
[['CAA46951', 'Homeobox domain', '192:248', 'F', '#CDC1C5', 'NULL', 'PFAM', 'Y', '433'], ['CAA46951', 'Homeodomain-like', '165:252', 'S', '#CD5B45', 'NULL', 'SCOP', 'Y', '433'], ['5330400P12', 'WD domain, G-beta repeat', '131:168', 'F', '#FF8C69', 'NULL', 'PFAM', 'Y', '296'], ['5330400P12', 'WD domain, G-beta repeat', '173:210', 'F', '#FF8C69', 'NULL', 'PFAM', 'Y', '296'], ['5330400P12', 'WD40-repeat', '1:296', 'S', '#00FF7F', 'NULL', 'SCOP', 'Y', '296'], ['AAH62206', 'Cell division protein', '38:311', 'S', '#00CED1', 'NULL', 'PFAM', 'Y', '425'], ['AAH62206', 'P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolases', '36:279', 'S', '#00FFFF', 'NULL', 'SCOP', 'Y', '425']]
```

If you wish to reduce further, you can do this:

```
newL=[filter(len, e.split('&')) for l in LofL for e in l]
```

Comment: I wish to marry you! This has been exactly how I've been trying to solve this for close to two weeks now and it wouldn't work! BUT YOU MADE IT WORK! THANKYOU!

Comment: @Paul Circi Tnisq: You can accept the answer and vote it up and we'll call it square ;-}

Comment: You can change the body to `newSubL = filter(None, e.split('&'))`

Comment: @Joel Cornett: Thanks! I did not see that immediately

Comment: @drewk I can't -.- Requires level 15 reputation. Stupid thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> oldList = [['a&b&c'], ['d&e&f']]
>>> newList = [item[0].split('&') for item in oldList]
>>> newList
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: I kind of need them in the list of list of strings later on in the coding (more for convenience than anything)
Also thats returning just the first element of each item but I think I can make it work. Thankyou!

Comment: @PaulCirciTnisq: It's returning the contents of each list in your master list. Does your each list in your master list contain more than one string?

Comment: No, but its returning each individual character in each list in the master list

Comment: @PaulCirciTnisq: `oldList` is the master list.

Comment: its returning each individual character in the lists of the master list though :/ All good though, I got it working.